# Can I use an instrument with the supine ablative of respect?

Tags: grammar-choice, ablative, ablativus-instrumenti, supinum, ablativus-respectus

If a book is easy to write, I might say *liber facilis est scriptu*.
Here the supine ablative *scriptu* is an ablative of respect (*ablativus respectus*).
If I want to be more specific about my writing, I could say *librum stilo scribo* instead of just *librum scribo*.
But can I use an instrument with the supine ablative as well and say *liber facilis est stilo scriptu*?
I do not recall ever seeing such a thing, and it feels a bit weird.
I think it is grammatical, but I want confirmation.
Are there examples of such use in literature or is this discussed in some grammar?

Comment: "I do not recall ever seeing such a thing, and it feels a bit weird" -- my feelings exactly.

Comment: related (IMO): https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13016/middle-constructions-in-latin