# "Middle constructions" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, verbs, reflexive-pronoun, middle-voice

I was wondering **how so-called ["middle constructions"](https://web.stanford.edu/~cleoc/mid.pdf)** like the English ones exemplified in (1), which are typically translated with a reflexive verb in Romance languages (e.g., see the Catalan examples in (2)), **are expressed in Latin**. See also this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z32uj-umTKw) for a very basic introduction to so-called "middle constructions" (in the sense of (some) recent linguistic literature).

> (1) a. Whales frighten easily.
>
> b. These dishes break easily.
>
> c. Messages transmit rapidly.

---

> (2) a. Les balenes s'espanten fàcilment.
>
> b. Aquests plats es trenquen fàcilment.
>
> c. Els missatges es transmeten ràpidament.

---

As pointed out by [Levin (1993: 5)](https://books.google.es/books?id=6wIZWOrcBf8C&pg=PA5&dq=%22middle%20construction%22%20Levin%20%22change%20of%20state%22&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwoN6knrHmAhWD2-AKHSYCCicQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=%22middle%20construction%22%20Levin%20%22change%20of%20state%22&f=false), only causative verbs of change (e.g., *frighten, break, open, dry,* etc.) typically enter into the so-called "middle construction" (in the sense of the abovementioned links). For example, according to her, stative verbs (e.g., *see, believe,* etc.) do not typically enter into this construction (e.g., **Whales see easily* is ill-formed).

I was wondering (i) whether a similar set of "middle constructions" can be identified in Latin and (ii) whether similar semantic restrictions like the ones pointed out above by Levin apply to their equivalent Latin constructions (e.g., reflexive and/or mediopassive constructions, constructions with deverbal adjectives ending with *-bilis* suffix, etc.).

NB I: here I'm specifically interested in those "middle constructions" that receive this (appropriate or not!) label in the (recent) linguistic literature above (e.g., see the links above). I.e., although it is related to this topic, my question is **not** whether there is a "middle voice" in Latin.

NB II: so-called "middle constructions" (again defined in the sense of links above) are typically separated from so-called "anticausative/ergative constructions" (see [this link](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7166/did-latin-have-any-ergative-verbs)): for example, the former can be formed from agentive verbs, whereas the latter can't (e.g., cf. the well-formedness of *These horses saddle easily* vs. the ill-formedness of **These horses saddled easily*. NB: the verb *saddle* (meaning 'to provide with a saddle') is necessarily agentive).

Comment: Perhaps of interest: https://thepatrologist.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Reconceiving-the-Middle-Voice-Greek-and-Latin.pdf

Comment: @EthanBierlein Thanks for this interesting document. I've taken a look at it and I've realized that it basically deals with the connection between (historical) "middle voice" and Latin deponent verbs. However, I've been unable to see any reference to the treatment of so-called "middle constructions" in the sense of the links/video above.

Comment: The basic answer is that Latin had already lost the middle voice, if it ever had any. Are you interested in the various substitutions under which the middle voice could be subsurmized, or only in the specific examples. I mean, I thought Spanish "the vase broke itself" was a proper continuation of middle voice, which McWorther talking about reflexive pronouns has compared to "the car broke down *on me*"

Comment: @vectory As noted above, so-called "middle constructions" (e.g., _These dishes break easily_) are different from ergatives (e.g., _These dishes broke_). The former have a **generic** meaning and often require an adverbial expression (e.g., _easily_). As noted above, agentive verbs can enter into the middle construction but not in the ergative one: cf. the well-formation of _These books {read/sell} well_ vs. the ill-formation of *_These books {read/sold}_. Note that "the vase broke (by itself)" (or its Romance equivalent with reflexive) is not a middle construction (in the sense above).

Comment: @Mitomano, and what about "these dishes broke easily"? I expect it has to be translated with care.

Comment: @vectory You're right. In some cases it is not always easy to distinguish them formally. Some nice contrasts given in the first link above are: cf. _*The glass broke with a hammer_ (ergative) with _This glass breaks easily with a hammer_ (middle). The former is ungrammatical, whereas the latter is ok. This contrast has to do with the fact that ergatives are incompatible with instrumentals, which require an agent, whereas middles are compatible with them. That's why middles are compatible with agentive verbs (_These books read/sell easily_), whereas ergatives aren't (*_These books read/sold_).

Answer (score 1):

I will make the argument that [**maturo**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=maturo) is such a verb. (which, in some respects, matches the English *ripen*/*grow* in this (which is not shared by other languages)).

First, its primary meaning is the *transitive* ripen: to bring to maturaty. "maturo uvas": I ripen grapes.

Now, In order to say "to ripen" *intransitively* (i.e., to mean "to become ripe or soft, to come to maturity") as in "honeydew melons ripen slowly" the passive verb of *maturo* can be used as L&S demonstrate. **Yet**, however, in L&S under II.A, we can find an intransitive use of *maturo* which seems to qualify into the definition. The only 2 examples given by L&S contain adverbs (*sero* and *tardius*):

> ficūs, quae sero maturant

Another example I could locate is from Pliny N.H:

> Alia etiamnum aetatis differentia. amygdala enim et pirus in senecta fertilissimae ut et glandiferae et quoddam genus ficorum, **ceterae in iuventa tardiusque maturantes** (... the rest, in youth, ripen slowly.

As *maturo* is a "a verb of change", and the examples given above are *general* in their nature, IMO it fits the definition nicely. Also I find the fact that *maturo* is used passively to convey the English intransitive meaning of *ripen*, to give more space, at least in theory, for a general meaning of a middle construction.

---

Not sure I understand the question well. On one side it seems to be interested in how to *express* middle construction in Latin, but also interested to identify  "middle construction". I view those as 2 separated things. Here I address only one issue (namely the existence of middle constructions in Latin).

Comment: Your examples exemplify the so-called "inchoative"/intr. variant associated to transitive causative verbs of change of state. Cf. the links in my question above and this footnote: https://books.google.es/books?id=6wIZWOrcBf8C&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=%22the+middle+alternation+should+not+be+confused+with+the+causative/inchoative+alternation%22&source=bl&ots=TC2ATYF_ZO&sig=ACfU3U28vwrZkYB-0ffhl6VN6Gm6wcfNCg&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiotbGq88HwAhXDx4UKHe5gBIUQ6AEwBnoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=%22the%20middle%20alternation%20should%20not%20be%20confused%20with%20the%20causative%2Finchoative%20alternation%22&f=false